# Converting String to an Integer/float when reading from a csv file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a file which includes numbers like ["75,000", "500,000", "255,000"].
I am not able to append these to a List as a integer or a float, I can only append it as a String. To me, it looks like it is due to the comma in the string value. I can print it as a String but not do arithmetic operations on them as they are string. Below is my try to append int to list. Please help with this.

```
Money = []

with open('Money.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        Money.append(int(row[4]))
```

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '75,000'

Comment: This is the error i get with that specific piece of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int` doesn't know how to handle the separating commas, you'll need to remove them.

```
Money.append(int(row[4].replace(',', '')))
```

However, you may want to consider to use `float` instead of `int` in case the csv file contains a decimal value.

Comment: This does remove the commas, but if i come to use this integer, say assign it to a variable it says it s not subscriptable? do you know a way around this?

Comment: @EthanVenencia What do you mean? why do you try to subscript an integer?

Comment: Im just trying to assing the now integer "75000" to a variable like so

Comment: T1P1 = prizeMoney[0][4] which is the 75000 integer but it says 'int' object is not subscritable

Comment: I can't help you if you don't show your full code. Do a `print(prizeMoney)` and see what value `prizeMoney` contains. You **can not** use `[...]` on integers.

Comment: Ok so i print(prizeMoney) and this prints [75000, 80000, 100000, 150000]

Comment: All i want to do is assign each one of those values to a variable

Comment: @EthanVenencia So it is a list. `prizeMoney[0]` will be the first number and so on. You don't need the second `[...]`, it has no meaning.

Comment: so T1P1 = prizeMoney[0], T1P2 = prizeMoney[1] and so on so then i can use the integers alone